# Where is ConcurrentDictionary in Reactive Extensions .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, system.reactive, concurrentdictionary

My questions is simple. After heavy googling I have learned that I can use **ConcurrentDictionary** in **.NET 3.5** projects using **Reactive Extensions** and **System.Threading.dll** version from its install directory. First of all there is no System.Threading.dll, there is only System.Reactive.Windows.Threading in Reactive Extensions .NET 3.5 subdirectory. **Adding reference to System.Reactive or System.Reactive.Windows.Threading or to any other from the mentioned .NET 3.5 doesn't give me ConcurrentDictionary class nor it gives me System.Collections.Concurrent namespace.** I have downloaded older version of Reactive Extensions SDK and I have found what I have been looking for but my question is: does anybody know what happened to the ConcurrentDictionary backport in actual release of Reactive Extensions, does anybody know where it is or why it is missing. I was not able to find a reasonable answer or any answer at all.

Comment: This might be of use to you: [Why might System.Threading.dll be missing from Windows\Assembly?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405662/why-might-system-threading-dll-be-missing-from-windows-assembly

Comment: Yes, I have seen this post. In my case everything is fine, I add the correct Rx version of the dll and it is visible in the References list. However, even if I use a decompiler on all of the dlls from Reactive Extensions there is no sign of ConcurrentDictionary, I mean in the actual version, old version is fine but I want to know what happened, why am I forced to use older version of Rx ?

Comment: The RX Extensions team have not given a reason why the concurrent data structures were removed. See here (if you haven't already): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/527002a3-18af-4eda-8e35-760ca0006b98#11b85c5b-f966-4b2a-9a94-b5d1c41394b7. I guess you would need to ask the team directly in order to find out. I suspect it has to do with RX extensions only officially being supported on NET 4.0, Silverlight 4, and Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Thanks Ɖiamond ǤeezeƦ, that makes things straight :)

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for the release where this was supported.. can you help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We no longer ship the backport of the TPL with Rx for .NET 3.5. If you want to use the TPL and associated innovations in the field of concurrency, start using .NET 4 (or beyond). Rx itself doesn't need TPL functionality, hence there was no strong need for us to carry around the TPL.

There are too many complications with regards to supportability, maintenance, and quality associated with keeping such a backport alive. For instance, performance characteristics of the TPL on older CLR versions has never been tested much beyond the initial CTP of the TPL several years ago.

Comment: Thanks very much for a detailed and competent answer.