# System.Threading is not found?

Tags: c#

in my device, Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013 are installed on my PC. Neither finds System.Threading although I have define the namespace.

Why ???

Comment: What sort of project are you working in and what references does it have?

Comment: Take a look at [Why might System.Threading.dll be missing from Windows\Assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405662/why-might-system-threading-dll-be-missing-from-windows-assembly)

Comment: @Liath: C#.net Console project

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the project has a reference to `mscorlib.dll`.

Comment: @user3289698 no they are different

Comment: iamkrillin@: Yes. I have found it. it is added to my project .